# LoadRunner: Path of downloaded file

Tags: file, http, path, loadrunner

I am recording a script on HTTP based protocol and I am saving a file, a pop up opens and saves a file (.doc) on my local computer,while replaying the script I want to check the downloaded file path...is there any method?
LoadRunner 9.52

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not have a file on replay.   Your download is coming in the context of the HTTP data flow.   If you log the information for the request you can check the log, but this still will not be a file that you can open.   Your best bet is to use web_reg_find() or web_reg_save_param() to check for the existence of both the file header and footer in your http download stream.   You also may want to check the size of the previous download.   Then at some logic like this (P-CODED)

```
If ( 
    file_header_exists 
    && file_footer_exists 
    && file_size>some_minimum_number_of_bytes 
)
then ( I_have_a_valid_downloaded_file )
```

Just inmagine what you would be doing to your local file system if you required that all of the files be written to the local file system during the performance test.  Your local hard drive would become a bottleneck for your entire load generator.

You might also consider running a single GUI Virtual User (Based upon QuickTest Professional Technology stack) to check for the one file download for a single user as a functional check.

If you are still engaging in functional checks then you are likely testing too soon for performance, for if it does not work for one then it will never work for many.